# Yii create application error on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, yii, terminal, installation

I have installed xampp on ubuntu 13.04, it works and its running. My Yii folder is in /opp/lampp/htdocs/Yii-Main so the yiic bash file is in opt/lampp/htdocs/Yii-Main/framework/yiic

I go to the framework directory and run the command:

sudo yiic webapp ../../test

And it says : "sudo: yiic: command not found"

If I run :

sudo ./yiic webapp ../../test

Then it just says : "sudo: ./yiic: command not found"

What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have PHP in your user path, that's the reason it doesn't know the command.
You can just run it like:

```
/opt/lampp/php yiic.php command name
```

change the `/opt/lampp/php` path to match yours.

Comment: I don't get it, I tried running: sudo /opt/lampp/php yiic.php webapp ../../ayiitest . It didn't work, it says "/opt/lampp/php" command not found. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install php5-cli and then you can run without any problem.